# Yeast Starter OG - Factoring in the WYeast Liquid

Tags: yeast-starters, wyeast

Is there any estimate to the "OG of the WYeast Liquid"?

When I make a yeast starter with an OG of 1.040, dumping in the WYeast liquid will bring it down, assuming that the liquid has an OG of less than 1.040, and I assume it would have an OG of 1.000.

Does anyone attempt to factor that in while making yeast starters with WYeast? How is it done?

Comment: why do you assume it has an OG of 1.000?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nutrient in a Wyeast pouch is around 1.020.  There's not enough of it there to have an appreciable effect on your starter gravity.  You can pretty much discount it entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you have answered this yourself in your post.

Since Wyeast liquid yeast is a 100% liquid yeast it does not contain any sugars that contribute to a higher OG. If it did contain any sugars it would start fermenting by itself in the tube...

In your case you do not need to take this into account but if you are worried about your starting not being "effective" enough you can take a look into this [BrewersFriends Starter Calculator](http://www.brewersfriend.com/yeast-pitch-rate-and-starter-calculator/) to calculate the amount of starter that you should use in order to get your yeast going enough for your brew.

Comment: The Wyeast pouch does contain sugars - it contains yeast in the main pouch and a sachet of growth medium. It doesn't ferment because the yeast and the growth media are kept separate until the pack is smacked (i.e. the sachet of growth medium - wort - is broken). You mention the yeast is in a tube - maybe you're thinking of White Labs yeast?

Comment: Although I agree that you don't have to take it into account, I downvoted because the statement that there are no fermentables in the pack is incorrect.

Comment: @MDMA so I broke my nutrient seal 36-48 hours before I made the starter because I couldn't get around to it 8 hours after I broke the nutrients. Would it start fermenting if I waited that long?

Comment: Yes, no problem. The yeast will still be viable and will propagate in the starter.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I am thinking of White Labs. My bad!